# how to make NSURLConnection's delegate protocol method called in this NSOperation instance?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

hello i have done this QCM in an iOS test. my choice is B. and it's wrong. i hope someone could help me understand. Thank you in advance.

Here is the question: 
NSURLConnection instance created and started inside the implementation of "start" method of the concurrent NSOperation.

What should be changed to make NSURLConnection's delegate protocol method call in this NSOperation instance?

```
-(void)start{
  ...
  _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self      startImmediately:NO];
  [_connection scheduleInRunloop: [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
  [_connection start];
  ... }
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
  {
  NSLog(@"Called"); }
```

there are three answers provide: 
A: Set startImmediately to YES

B: Wrap this code to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(),^{});

C: Nothing, didReceiveResponse will be called.

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine. (Obviously, there's much more to `NSOperation` subclass, but I'm assuming you've implemented that, too. Does `isAsynchronous`/`isConcurrent` return `TRUE`?) This is the a valid way to create `NSURLConnection` in `NSOperation` subclass. You should not set `startImmediately` to `YES`. Nor do you need to do that `dispatch_async`. Are you saying that the code snippet provided is having some problem? It's unclear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @Rob I think the question is along the lines of "what needs to be done to make sure that the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method `didReceiveResponse:` is called automatically when the NSOperation is added to a queue.. and I guess this is assuming a valid response. And along the lines of what you're saying, I think the answer would be C, the code is fine as is... `start` gets called when you add this to an operation queue, which in turn properly sets up the NSURLConnection, which in turn will call its delegate when the response is received

Comment: @LouisTur Agreed. Yes, I'm saying "C", too. I'm just trying to figure out why he's asking the question at all, because I presume he wouldn't be asking the question if everything was working swimmingly. I'm actually assuming that he's not seeing his delegate methods called for some reason and is grasping as possible solutions. And if that's the case, the problem obviously rests elsewhere in his code. Maybe some issue with not returning `TRUE` from `isAsynchronous`/`isConcurrent`. Or is incorrectly returning wrong value from `isFinished`. Or isn't doing necessary KVN on prior operations. Or...

Comment: (By the way, I know you know this, but `start` obviously does not get called when you add it to the queue. It's called when the queue starts the operation. If it's backlogged behind other operations on a queue, or what have you, it won't start until enough of those other operations finish.)

Comment: @LouisTur Thanks guys.Indeed,the didReceiveResponse: is called automatically when NSOperation added to a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No change is necessary to this code sample (option C).

Setting `startImmediately` to `YES` (option A) would merely start the connection prior to scheduling it on the appropriate run loop, which would cause problems.

You could, theoretically dispatch the creation of the connection to the main thread (option B), thus eliminating the need to manually schedule it on the main run loop. But your code sample (manually scheduling it on the main run loop) accomplishes the same thing and is the more common pattern.

Bottom line, you existing code sample is fine.